# Justification in change of variables

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, contour-integration

it would be fantastic if anyone could help me with the following problem:

I have the integral

$$\operatorname{Im} \left( \int^\infty_0 e^{it} t^{s-1} \mathrm{d} t\right)$$

and I wish to make the variable change $t \to ib$

to give

$$\operatorname{Im} \left( i^{s} \int^\infty_0 e^{-b} b^{s-1} \mathrm{d} b \right) $$

so that I may derive something later on. The only thing is, I am changing the variable and so I change the contour too. Anybody know how to justify that the above holds over the imaginary axis?

Cheers

Comment: If you are trying to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin (t) \ t^{s-1} \ dt $, integrate $f(z) = e^{iz} z^{s-1}$ around a closed quarter circle in the first quadrant that is indented at the origin.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, but you could look at $t$ in the following way

$t = a + ib \qquad t \in [0,\infty) $

where $a=0$. Hence, it follows that $ib$ exists in $[0,\infty)$ of the imaginary plane. And it would also follow that

$\mathrm{d}t = i \cdot \mathrm{d}b $

which you have already made allowances for.